# When I set the Owner property of a WPF child window, am I preventing it from getting garbage collected?

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection

If parent window A passes a reference to itself to child window B (via constructor) so that B can set its Owner property to A, does that mean child window B won't be garbage collected because parent window A stays alive for the duration of the application?

If this is the case, what is the best approach for creating clean parent/child relationships between WPF windows?  Is there a concept of weak references for this type of relationship?

**UPDATE:** Brain FAIL.  Okay, I shouldn't have asked this question so late in the afternoon.  I was over-complicating the problem.  My brain reversed the logic of the GC and was thinking the child couldn't collect because it referenced something else which is totally false.  Thanks to all who answered anyway.

Comment: When you close and are done with child window B, make sure that the Owner property gets set to null. The reference will be disconnected and it should be eventually gced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the Windows you mention, and added some code:

```
// XAML in Window A

<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Show Window</Button>
    <Button Click="Button_Click_1">Garbage Collect</Button>
</StackPanel>

// Code in Window A
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowB windowB = new WindowB(this);
            windowB.Show();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }

    // Code in WindowB
    public WindowB(WindowA windowA)
    {
        this.Owner = windowA;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ~WindowB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Gone up in a puff of smoke");
    }
```

Once B had been closed and the second button pressed, the destructor ran. Hopefully this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are eligible for garbage collection as soon as no references to them exist in the stack.  For this reason as long as you hold a reference to `window B` within `window A` then it will never be garbage collected.

In order to make it eligible for GC you'll have to explicitly set any reference to it to null or another object reference.

Answer (score 1):

> If parent window A passes a reference to itself to child window B (via
>   constructor) so that B can set its Owner property to A, does that mean
>   child window B won't be garbage collected because parent window A
>   stays alive for the duration of the application?

Correct, child window B lives until parent Window A lives, because there is a live reference from Parent window to WindowB.

> If this is the case, what is the best approach for creating clean
>   parent/child relationships between WPF windows? Is there a concept of
>   weak references for this type of relationship?

Clear the Parent window reference to Window B when the WindowB close. In this way, there is no live reference to WindowB and it's eligible to garbage collected.

```
parentWindow.WindowB = null;
```

One more thing, it's a good practice to call the Dispose method for all the Disposable objects before they go out of scope. You can use `using` statement for local/disposable objects.

Comment: I like this answer over all others.